# Heroku pipeline config vars

Tags: heroku, ember.js

I've been having this issue many times. When I promote my staging app to production its config vars are not loaded properly. Right now my production app is using my staging's config vars. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines):

> Pipelines only manage the application slug. The Git repo, config vars,
>   add-ons and other environmental dependencies are not considered part
>   of a pipeline and must be managed independently.

So if your "build artifact" (i.e. your slug) contains config vars from your staging app, it will get promoted to prod. All pipelines really do is allow you to skip the slug compilation by simply using the exact same slug from the previous environment. If you cannot remove config vars from the slug compilation for your code base in the staging environment, I would avoid pipelines.

Note: this is true as of the time this answer was submitted, who knows if Heroku will be able to change this in the future.

Comment: Oh I think now I understand the problem. Wouldn't a reset of the app create the slug again? And if not, is there a way to do that so my config vars are loaded again?

Comment: If by reset you mean `heroku restart -a yourProdApp`, then no. That restart simply reboots the dyno and does not build a new slug. To get the config vars into the slug, you have to trigger a build, e.g. `git push heroku master`. One reason why this problem exists is that config vars are meant to be used at run time and not at build time.

Comment: Here's a newer SO answer that gives a more detailed answer to this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45064842/heroku-pipeline-staging-env-variable-carried-into-production