# Heroku pipeline - staging env variable carried into production

Tags: heroku, webpack, heroku-pipelines

I've recently deployed a React/Express app to Heroku, but I'm having an issue with environment variables that are part of the built app and the Heroku deployment pipeline - in a nutshell, the values of environment variables from the app's `staging` release are being carried over when promoting to `production` - the only way that I can get the environment variables to set correctly is to push the app directly to `production`, which really defeats the purpose of the deployment pipeline in the first place. Here's a summary of the scenario:

The environment variable in question is `API_URL`, which is referenced in `webpack.config.js` like so:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'API_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL || 'http://localhost:4000/api/v1')
    })
]
```

The API is itself another Heroku app with `staging` and `production` releases, and so the values of the `API_URL` environment variable are set in my React app Heroku configuration as `https://staging-api-12345.herokuapp.com/api/v1` and `https://production-api-12345.herokuapp.com/api/v1`, respectively.

When I push my React app up to `staging`, it works perfectly - however, when I promote the app to `production` and make the first call to the API, it is still pointing to `https://staging-api-12345.herokuapp.com/api/v1`. Ok well, I understand why that is the case - the app was built when being pushed to `staging`... so I tried rebuilding the app after promoting to `production`, but that did not work, it still used the `staging` environment variables.

When using the Heroku deployment pipeline, is there a way to force the app slug to rebuild so that it will catch the different environment variables?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot rebuild the slug, the main point of pipelines is to move the same slug between apps.

What you need to do is to fetch `API_URL` at runtime and not during build process. You can put all envs in one file, for example `env.js`

```
export const API_URL = process.env.API_URL;
export const OTHER_VAR = process.env.OTHER_VAR;
```

And then just import what you need in other files

```
import { API_URL, OTHER_VAR } from 'env.js';
```

Comment: What about for just a static app which is not using Express?

Comment: What's your setup exactly? I believe you can use the same approach. All you need to do is to make sure that you fetch ENV on runtime and not during build process.

Comment: My environment variables are undefined when I use this method. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

There might be situations where you need env vars during build time for different environments further downstream the pipeline. A setup like this for example:

```
Test |--> Prd Europe
     |--> Prd USA
```

Say, for SEO reasons, you want to have a different title for USA by using the env vars and it should be immediately available in the template, not after some miliseconds. This is in a pipeline not possible since the slug is built at test where only a single tenant can be served, and async loading is too slow. Some crawler may pick the placeholder title instead for example.

A workaround for this, besides not using a pipeline altogether, could be to generate multiple templates per environment (at build time). In this case two templates `europe.html` and `usa.html`. Then serve them based on the env vars at runtime by a web server. So `if REGION === 'USA'`, serve `usa.html` with the env vars baked in at the test env.