# Heroku nuxt production deployment is using staging config vars

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using heroku to deploy my nuxt.js frontend app, and set a config var for the api url.

When I promote an app from staging to production, the production site uses the config vars from staging.

Doing some research I can see this is because nuxt sets the env vars at build-time instead of runtime, and the app is built in the staging environment.

As a result any api requests in the production app use the staging api.

What is the best way around this without any potential adverse effects?

Comment: set the heroku prod configs ( ENV vars) using the heroku dashboard... https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: I have already done this, the production environment is is using the staging env vars though

Comment: Theres a potential solution here, though I worry there may be security implications by doing it this way or some other unforeseen adverse effect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45064842/heroku-pipeline-staging-env-variable-carried-into-production

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way I got around this issue was by creating a separate heroku app for staging using staging config vars (no pipeline). I then create a pipeline for production, with a production-staging app and production-live app, using production config vars for both.

Once i've tested the staging app, I then push to production-staging where the app is build and finally promote to production-live.

Comment: Then why do you need a pipeline? You could create one staging app and one production app.